# Why I am getting access to other class' private members?

Tags: c++, class, private

```
class Complex
{
private:
    float real, imaginary;
public:
    Complex(float real, float imaginary)
    {
        this->real = real;
        this->imaginary = imaginary;
    }
    float getReal() const
    {
        return this->real;
    }
    float getImaginary() const
    {
        return this->imaginary;
    }
    Complex operator+(Complex other)
    {
        return Complex(this->real + other.real, this->imaginary + other.imaginary); // Here I can access other class' private member without using getter methods.
    }
};

int main()
{
    Complex first(5, 2);
    Complex second(7, 12);
    Complex result = first + second; // No error
    std::cout << result.getReal() << " + " << result.getImaginary() << "i"; // But here I have to use getters in order to access those members.
    return 0;
}
```

Why I am getting access to a class' private members from another class? I thought I have to use getters to access other class' private members. But it turns out, that if I call it from another class, it no longer requires those getters and I can access them directly. But this is not possible outside of that class.

Comment: "_Here I can access other class' private member without using getter methods._" But you aren't accessing other class' members. It's class `Complex`, accessing members, of class `Complex`. What, exactly, is the problem here?

Comment: The fundamental problem is distinguishing between another class and another object.    `private` is private to the *class*, not the object. Both `*this` and `other` are objects of class `Complex`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Complex result = first + second;
```

This invokes operator+ for Complex class, operator itself is part of Complex class so it has access to all members of this class, even for `other` instance passed as an argument.

```
std::cout << result.getReal() << " + " << result.getImaginary() << "i";
```

operator<< is not defined for your class, so you have to pass 'something printable' to cout's << operator. You cannot simply write `result.real` because it is private in this context, that is, outside of `Complex` class.

Answer (score 2):

It's not another class; it's another *instance*, and functions in an `A` can access `private` members of another `A`. That's just how it works. Otherwise it would be impossible to do things like you've done, and we need to be able to do those things.